# MySQL join three tables, sum of item join to main table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three MySQL tables:

For example

- A Table is menu    ID, name
- B table is customer_order ID, order_date
- C table is order_item ID, menu_item_id, customer_order_id, order_quantity

I try to output name, sum(order_quantity) in this month

Currently i have two separate query which working ok, but the second query is inside of foreach loop, which seem not so good.

First query which output all the menu items:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM menu WHERE post_id = $pid ORDER BY sort_order ");
```

Second query will output total of each item sold on each month:

```
$total = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT SUM(oi.order_item_quantity) 
                          from order_item as oi 
                          INNER JOIN customer_order as ho ON ho.ID = oi.order_id  
                          WHERE oi.order_item_id =  $subC->ID AND YEAR(ho.order_date) = $current_year AND MONTH(ho.order_date) = $current_month ");
```

I try to merge the two queries into one query, which has taken me whole day but still not able to solve it, can anyone give me some help please.

**update**

thanks Rene.

```
Select m.name, m.name as name, sum(oi.order_item_quantity) as sold_monthly from menu as m left join order_item as oi on oi.order_item_id = m.ID left join cusomter_order as co on co.ID = oi.order_id where m.post_id = 110  group by m.ID, m.name
```

this will output

```
 name                   sold_monthly    
Sushi Lunch Special     NULL
Sushi Lunch             19
Sashimi Lunch           61
jason                   NULL
egg roll                NULL
```

if i add `YEAR(co.order_date) = 2016 AND MONTH(co.order_date) = 9`

which i only get

```
 name                   sold_monthly    
Sushi Lunch             7
Sashimi Lunch           14
```

how can i keep  sushi lunch special, jason, egg roll, the null item, when i add the `YEAR(co.order_date) = 2016 AND MONTH(co.order_date) = 9.`

here i try

```
(year(co.order_date) = 2016 and month(co.order_date) = 10) or sold_monthly is null
```

which give me a query error

**update
thanks Rene again**

it's working now

```
 (year(co.order_date) = 2016 and month(co.order_date) = 10) or co.order_date is null
```

**finally solve it, upper have little bug, when i change business_id which may not catch the result i want, so i am add a subquery to it.**

```
Select m.*, p.sold_monthly from menu as m left join ( SELECT SUM(oi.order_item_quantity) as sold_monthly, oi.order_item_id as ID, oi.order_item_name from order_item as oi LEFT JOIN cusomter_order as ho ON ho.ID = oi.order_id WHERE ho.business_id = $pid AND (year(ho.order_date) = $current_year and month(ho.order_date) = $current_month) OR ho.order_date is NULL GROUP by oi.order_item_id )p on p.ID = m.ID where m.post_id = $pid
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would greatly help explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're trying to get a list per post_id limited by the selected month.
The following query will yield that for the following sample data.

```
SELECT m.ID as ID, m.Name as Name, SUM(oi.order_quantity) as Quantity
FROM menu as m
LEFT JOIN order_item as oi ON oi.menu_item_id = m.ID 
LEFT JOIN customer_order as co ON co.ID = oi.customer_order_id
WHERE m.post_id = 0 AND YEAR(co.order_date) = 2016 AND MONTH(co.order_date) = 9 OR co.order_date is NULL
GROUP BY m.ID,m.Name,m.sort_order
ORDER BY m.sort_order
```

Sample Data

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `customer_order`;
CREATE TABLE `customer_order` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `order_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_german2_ci;

TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_order`;
INSERT INTO `customer_order` (`ID`, `order_date`) VALUES
(1, '2016-09-06 00:00:00'),
(2, '2016-09-13 00:00:00'),
(3, '2016-08-09 00:00:00'),
(4, '2016-09-19 00:00:00');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `menu`;
CREATE TABLE `menu` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sort_order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_german2_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_german2_ci;

TRUNCATE TABLE `menu`;
INSERT INTO `menu` (`ID`, `sort_order`, `post_id`, `Name`) VALUES
(2, 0, 0, 'Test 1'),
(4, 1, 0, 'Test 2'),
(5, 2, 0, 'Test 3');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `order_item`;
CREATE TABLE `order_item` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `menu_item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `customer_order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `order_quantity` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_german2_ci;

TRUNCATE TABLE `order_item`;
INSERT INTO `order_item` (`ID`, `menu_item_id`, `customer_order_id`, `order_quantity`) VALUES
(1, 2, 1, 1),
(2, 2, 2, 3),
(3, 4, 1, 1),
(4, 4, 2, 4),
(5, 2, 3, 3),
(6, 4, 3, 1),
(7, 2, 4, 4);


ALTER TABLE `customer_order`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);

ALTER TABLE `menu`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  ADD KEY `idx_pid` (`post_id`);

ALTER TABLE `order_item`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  ADD KEY `idx_coid` (`customer_order_id`),
  ADD KEY `idx_miid` (`menu_item_id`);


ALTER TABLE `customer_order`
  MODIFY `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=5;
ALTER TABLE `menu`
  MODIFY `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=6;
ALTER TABLE `order_item`
  MODIFY `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=8;

ALTER TABLE `order_item`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `CostomerOrderConstrain` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_order_id`) REFERENCES `customer_order` (`ID`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `MenuItemConstrain` FOREIGN KEY (`menu_item_id`) REFERENCES `menu` (`ID`);
```

Good luck integrating the query, let me know if it worked.

Update: Updated sample data to reproduce the actual problem. Updated the Solution Query.

Comment: thanks my friend, but there is a little problem, which i post on new comment bottom, can you take a look please

Comment: thank you so much Rene, it's working perfect, thanks again ^^